# SQL: Get Frequency counter, similar to pivot table

Tags: sql, count, pivot, vertica

I have the following Table in a Vertica Database

```
+---------+-------+
| ReadOut | Event |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | A     |
|       1 | A     |
|       1 | B     |
|       1 | B     |
|       2 | A     |
|       2 | B     |
|       2 | B     |
+---------+-------+
```

I am trying to get the frequency of each event per read out. Maybe I am missusing the term 'frequency' in this case, but ideally at the end I would have a table like this:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+--+
| Frequency | Event_A | Event_B |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+
| 1         |       1 |       0 |  |
| 2         |       1 |       2 |  |
| 3         |       0 |       0 |  |
| 4         |       0 |       0 |  |
| .         |       0 |       0 |  |
| .         |       0 |       0 |  |
| .         |       0 |       0 |  |
+-----------+---------+---------+--+
```

So far I implemented a for loop in python that looks like this (simplified version):

```
# get all the available event names
Eventlist=SELECT DISTINCT Event FROM table
# loop over each event to get the frequency
for ii in Eventlist:
    SELECT count(Readout) FROM table WHERE Event = ii group by Readout
```

But the disadvante is that I need to know the names of the Events in advance which requires a seperate query and I have to run a bunch of loops.
Is there a more elegant way of doing this.
Thanks Mates

Comment: You're missing a sequence/timestamp column

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertica does not have the ability to pivot. You'll need to generate the sql to pivot or just pivot in python. I would just do it in python, keep your query simple.

As for getting counts per event, you can do it all at one time:

```
with f as (
    SELECT readout, event, COUNT(*) frequency
    FROM   mytable
    GROUP BY 1, 2 
)
select frequency, event, count(*) cnt
from f
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
```

Then use python to pivot and fill in the frequency gaps if you need to. (If you use pandas, pivoting is probably dead simple).

Here is an example pivoting to a dict (depends on which lib you are using and settings for your connection, so you'll probably need to change it):

```
from collections import defaultdict

myresult = defaultdict(dict)
for row in rows: 
    myresult[row['frequency'][row['event']] = row['cnt']
```

I'm sure there is some more clever way to do it with dict comprehension but this seems straightforward.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helps tremendously. Thank you, very much!